# Finite automaton issue: the proposed solution has a fourth state, whereas I found only 3.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, finite-automata

The task is:

Construct a determistic finite automaton M, with a maximum of four states, that recognizes all binary strings that starts with a 0, and has an odd number of 1's.

I've included a image of my answer, and the correct solution. What am I doing wrong? Why does the solution include the state $s_3$? Is it because it's a determistic automaton, and without it I don't account for all possible strings?

[The machines in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew6XM.png)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The specs are ambiguous.  Is it just "has an odd number of 1's" or "the 0 is followed by a string of an odd number of 1's"?  The first possibility allows multiple zeros to be interspersed among the 1's.

Comment: It's the first option. That's why the machine can loop between $s_2$ and $s_1$.

Comment: Do you agree with the more condensed title I propose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have have something for the machine to do in case it encounters a $1$ at the start of the string. Your machine doesn't work then, while the solution goes into an eternal loop in state $S_3$.

Comment: Aah, that clears it up. Thank you.

Comment: @Smebbs My guess is the definition of "deterministic automata" used here implies that the automata is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Complete_and_incomplete)